# JavaScript: Uncaught ReferenceError: confirm_Logout is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm pretty new to javascript...right now I'm just writing that dynamic logout button that will go log the user out before reloading the page. I wrote the function (this is actually my entire script.js file):

```
var scriptLoaded = true;
function confirm_logout()
{
   var logout = GetURL('logout_confirm.php');
   if(logout == 'true')
   {
      location.reload(true);
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

And then I'm loading it up with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js">
   var scriptLoaded = false;
</script>
```

So what I'd like is just put it inside an anchor tag, but for the sake of testing (it wasn't working, and I just wanted to slim it down) I did this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var LoggedOut = false;
   if(scriptLoaded == true)
   {
       LoggedOut = confirm_Logout();
   }
   document.write(LoggedOut);
</script>
```

Then I run it in chrome and in the debugging console I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: confirm_Logout is not defined (anonymous function).

Help me stack overflow, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `confirm_logout`, not `confirm_Logout` (lowercase 'l').

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var LoggedOut = false;
   if(scriptLoaded == true)
   {
       LoggedOut = confirm_logout();
   }
   document.write(LoggedOut);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute Javascript in a `script` element if it has a `src` it's referencing. Also, you defined `confirm_logout` and you are calling `confirm_Logout`, capital `L` which is why you get `confirm_Logout` is not defined.